# Dangling participles and more

Tags: dangling-participles

I'm writing a paper and I have two questions about the sentence below.

> The mineral derangements, represented by **A** and **B**, in the patients at the chronic phase after transplantation were strongly associated with the former **C** in a positive and negative direction, respectively.

, where **A**, **B**, and **C** are clinical parameters.

My questions are:

1. I have two modifiers for the word "derangements;" one is "represented by ~" and the other is "in the patents ~." Is the order of these phrases correct? It sounds a little awkward to me.
2. **A** was positively associated with **C**, while **B** was negatively associated with **C**. Does it sound strange when I say "in a positive and negative direction, respectively?" Let me know if there is a better way to write.

Thanks in advance,
Nao

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The "definite article" you mentioned was... which one? I used so many definite articles in this sentences. That's another problem for me, though.

Comment: If you mean the measurements went up in one case and down in the other, I'd say so.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Notwithstanding my own answer I think I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

Your modifiers are unambiguous, no problem there.

Your *positive (A) and negative (B) direction, respectively* is clear.

I would say ***in/during*** the chronic phase.

But your sentence is long and not very easy to parse. This is not uncommon in scientific literature, but I would still advise you to split it. An example:

> Two types[?] of mineral derangement occurred[?] in patients during the chronic phase after transplantation, represented by A and B; type A shows a strong positive correlation with C, while B shows a strong negative correlation with C.

Perhaps I did not understand the terminology of your paper well enough to phrase everything properly, but I would split the sentence in this way.

Answer (score 1):

I. It sounds fine but I would drop the definite article. 2. I would re-arrange it slightly.

But my overall suggestion here would be to break it into two sentences: *The mineral derangements in patients at the chronic phase after transplantation were studied. Those represented by A and B were associated with the former C, respectively in a positive and negative direction.*

Reducing the sentence structure to manageable proportions would seem important, since I assume A, B and C, are merely substitutes for worded expressions.